# Why is splitting strings inconsistent?

Tags: ruby, string, split

Examine:

```
"test.one.two".split(".") # => ["test", "one", "two"]
```

Right, perfect. Exactly what we want.

```
"test..two".split(".") # => ["test", "", "two"]
```

I replaced `one` with the empty string, so that makes sense

```
"test".split(".") # => ["test"]
```

That's what I would expect, no problems here.

```
".test".split(".") # => ["", "test"]
```

Yep, my string has one `.` so I got two sections as a result.

```
"test.".split(".") # => ["test"]
```

What? There's a `.` in my string, it should have been split into two sections. I didn't ask to get rid of empty strings; it didn't get rid of empty strings back in tests 2 or 4.
I would have expected `["test", ""]`

```
"".split(".") # => []
```

WHAT?  This should operate almost *exactly* like test 3, and return `[""]`. But now I can't perform any string methods on `result[0]`

Why is this inconsistent for splits that occur on the edges, or for the empty string?

Comment: To yield all the parts in 5 one should pass a parameter to `split`: `"test.".split(".", -1) #⇒ ["test", ""]`. Empty string is always splitted into empty array.

Comment: @mudasobwa I know, my question is *why*. The empty string test behaves inconsistently with test 3.

Comment: from docs _When the input str is empty an empty Array is returned as the string is considered to have no fields to split._

Comment: @tihom Hmm, although that is the official answer, it's not a very satisfying one. It's arguable that there IS a field to split, and the value in it is empty. All in all though, it's likely simply a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation explains this well: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split

> If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed.  If limit is a positive number, at most that number of
>   fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned
>   as the only entry in an array).  If negative, there is no limit to the
>   number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not
>   suppressed.

So, this does what you'd expect:

```
"test.".split(".", -1)
 => ["test", ""]
```

The rest is there in the docs.

Comment: Even with the `-1` parameter, the empty string splits incorrectly;  `"".split(".", -1) # => []`. But even though the documentation details that behaviour, I would like to know *why*; it is counterintuitive IMO.

Comment: On a tangetially related point, having a negative parameter is nonsense. It would make more sense for you to pass in an optional option hash with `suppress_trailing_null_fields: false` or something like that. Having a negative number of fields doesn't intuitively mean that. Although I understand the value of accepting an integer in its place.

Comment: At that point, you might want to go on the ruby core team irc channels and ask why they designed it that way.